# count(*) and count(*) over () performance difference in greenplum/postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I want to query the detail data and the total number of detail data. In general, this requires two sentences of SQL. For example, one is `select col1, col2, col3 from tb limit 50 offset 0`, another one is `select count() from tb`. In order to reduce the number of queries, I use "select col1, col2, col3, count() over () totol_count from tb" instead.

But I find that the latter(`select col1, col2, col3, count(*) over () totol_count from tb limit 50 offset 0`) is sometimes much slower than the former.  Why?
What is the performance difference between the two methods?

Here is the EXPLAIN ANALYZE.I just put the different on it.

1. select col1 from tb limit 20 offset 0
   Limit  (cost=743828.93..747114.71 rows=200 width=287) (actual time=2290.254..2390.969 rows=200 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Motion 20:1  (slice3; segments: 20)  (cost=743828.93..747114.71 rows=200 width=287) (actual time=2290.248..2390.933 rows=200 loops=1)
   ->  Limit  (cost=743828.93..747110.71 rows=10 width=287) (actual time=2285.350..2385.507 rows=200 loops=1)
2. select count(*) from tb
   Aggregate  (cost=6123212.33..6123212.34 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2339.615..2339.616 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Motion 20:1  (slice2; segments: 20)  (cost=6123212.10..6123212.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=635.672..2339.433 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Aggregate  (cost=6123212.10..6123212.11 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=633.879..633.879 rows=1 loops=1)
3. select col, count(*) over() from tb limit 20 offset 0
   Limit  (cost=743828.93..747113.21 rows=200 width=287) (actual time=57787.942..57788.339 rows=200 loops=1)
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=743828.93..307341631.82 rows=18670608 width=287) (actual time=57787.936..57788.310 rows=200 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Motion 20:1  (slice3; segments: 20)  (cost=743828.93..307014896.18 rows=18670608 width=287) (actual time=1514.368..32796.802 rows=18735134 loops=1)

Comment: look at execution plans , also paste them here for both queries , use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS` . also do you run these queries as is or are they inside a proc? or  in another way?

Comment: Thanks for asking such good question.

Comment: Because one counts all the rows in the table while the other doesn't.

Comment: When you post the EXPLAIN please format result keeping the indentation. One method would be by creating 2 lines in your question containing just ``` on each, then past the explain plan result between them.

Answer (score 0):

Only after seeing your execution plans it can be determined for sure which is better option for you.

But if you run [Analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) enough you can use:

```
SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  oid = 'tb'::regclass;
```

It's extremely fast but will not give you accurate count rather approximate one. Accuracy will depend on the frequency of running Analyze.

> The reason why `select count(*) from tb` slow is related to the MVCC
> implementation in PostgreSQL. The fact that multiple transactions can
> see different states of the data means that there can be no
> straightforward way for "COUNT(*)" to summarize data across the whole
> table; PostgreSQL must walk through all rows, in some sense. This
> normally results in a sequential scan reading information about every
> row in the table.
> [Slow counting in PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting)

Comment: I want an exact number of rows, not an estimate.In fact, the proportion of real queries is much more complex.It's not just a single table query.My question is : What is the performance difference between detail query with count(*) over and  2 query(detail query and count(*))?